# Help Identifying toilet tank make and model

Tags: bathroom, repair, toilet, replacement

I am trying to identify the make and model number of this toilet tank so I can replace the insides which is old and disintegrating and causing flushing and leaking issues.

Based on the fill valve inside the tank it might be a Mansfield but I am not sure about that since I can't find a matching image on https://www.plumbingsupply.com/mansfield-toilets.html or anywhere else online.

Can anyone definitively identify this toilet tank? any images or online sources would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Front image]
[image: Side image]
[image: Label inside tank]
[image: label on toilet base bottom 1]
[image: label on toilet base bottom 2]
[image: inside of tank]
[image: fill valve top view]

Comment: I have rebuilt well over a hundred toilets and to tell the truth a standard fill valve from fluid master for 5-10$ has always worked on simple gravity flush toilets.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like fairly typical old toilet guts. You should be able to replace with any "standard" kit - Fluidmaster, Danco, etc. The parts are actually (a bit surprisingly) very much standardized. I suggest making sure it is a kit that is adjustable to handle the old (water wasting) and new (low flow) toilets. 1993 was in the middle of the transition to low flow toilets, so it is hard to guess what type yours is. I would replace everything inside the tank at one time.